# Find the derived of an implicit given function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Let $C=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb(R)^3| \sin x + \sin^2 y + \sin^4 z=0 \ \text{and} \ (x-z)^2=4\pi^2\}.$

By the implicit function theorem, we have that $C$ can be parametrized as a smooth curve in the form of a graph, in a neighborhood $I$ of the point $(0,0,-2\pi)$, in the form of $t \mapsto \gamma(t)=(x(t),t,z(t))$, with $t \in I$, where I is an open interval around $0$ in $\mathbb(R)$ og $t \mapsto x(t)$ and $t \mapsto z(t)$ are smooth functions on $I$.

Find $\gamma'(0)$ and $\gamma''(0).$

We see that $C=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb(R)^3| F(x,y,z)=(0,0)\}$ where $F(x,y,z)=(\sin x + \sin^2 y + \sin^4 z, (x-z)^2-4\pi^2)$.

Since $\gamma$ is a reparametrization on $I$, it must have the same properties as $F$ on $I$, so if i derive $F$ and insert $0$, i guess i would obtain $\gamma ' (0)$ ? if this is not correct, im lost.

Edit:
\begin{align*}
DF(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos x & 2\sin y \cos y & 4 \sin^3 z \cos z \\
2(x-z) & 0 & -2(x-z)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
DF(0,0,0)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: You could accept more answers. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your idea is good. What's keeping you from making progress?

Comment: Because i was unsure, and would like to get my idea verified. But i will proceed right away, and edit it in asap.

Answer (score 2):

Since the values of second derivatives are requested it is not sufficient to look at $DF$. I suggest the following:

The second constraint defines the two planes $z=x\pm 2\pi$. Given the initial condition $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,-2\pi)$ it follows that $z=x-2\pi$, so that we are left with the single constraint
$$\sin x+\sin^2 y+\sin^4 x=0\ ,\tag{1}$$
connecting the variables $x$ and $y$. Now we want the curve $\gamma$ in the form
$$\gamma: \quad t\mapsto \bigl(x(t), t, z(t)\bigr)\ .$$
Plugging the "Ansatz" $$x(t):=a t+ b t^2+?t^3$$
into $(1)$ gives
$$ (at +bt^2)+t^2+?t^3=0\ ,$$
from which we conclude $a=0$, $\>b=-{1\over2}$. As $z(t)=x(t)-2\pi$ we finally obtain 
$$\gamma'(0)=(0,1,0),\quad \gamma''(0)=(-1,0,-1)\ .$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to find the hessian matrix of F?

Comment: You wouldn't know what to do with it; nor would I, for that matter.

Comment: okay thanks for the help. this is really useful.